# Geoserver viewshed WPS not found

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, viewshed, wps

I've googled for making viewshed analysis using Geoserver WPS, but didn't find any result. Also I've searched the WPS functions that Geoserver supports but didn't find viewshed.

Does Geoserver support viewshed?
If not, how to make such analysis.

My Environment is Geoserver, PostGIS, and Openlayers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box GeoServer WPS does not have a viewshed process.

One can be written, or you can bridge to another software (e.g., GRASS) that can do it.

Both option require coding (so either your coding time, or check out commercial support: http://geoserver.org/support/ )